# IIS URLRewrite Module

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

Ok, this may sound like a silly question anymore, but now that there doesn't appear to be an active IIS URLRewrite Forum any longer, how in the heck do we know WHAT is the latest actual version of URLRewrite? I've seen folks talk about 7.2.1993, 7.2.2, 7.2.3, etc., however when I go to the iis.net rewrite page and download the 64 bit version, the version of the dll is 7.1.1933.2531. Not 7.2.1993, etc.

Does anyone have a definitive version matrix of IIS URLRewrite and which ones are Rewrite 2.0 and 2.1? Also, who's crazy idea was it to make the Name and Versions entirely different? Is there any official/unofficial support for this any longer?

Thank you,

Comment: Once installed, URL Rewrite module is considered part of IIS so you can open support cases via https://support.microsoft.com if you have an active support contract. There isn't a public place with all releases notes together, so the public information is never enough to answer your questions.

Comment: You can download the latest URL rewrite module via this official Microsoft link: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite#additionalDownloads, If it is installed, you can check Control Panel > Installed Programs and find the install version there. As Lex Li said, official support from Microsoft can be sought.